# magento get coupon details from price rule

Tags: magento

How do i get the coupons details from rule id.

i am able to getting all the rules from the following code,

```
$sopping_cart_rules = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')->load();
    $sopping_cart_rule_info = array();
    foreach ($sopping_cart_rules as $rule) {
        //only for active rules
         if ($rule->getIsActive()) {
            $sopping_cart_rule_info['shopping_cart_rules'] = array(
                'id'=>$rule->getId(),
                'name'=>$rule->getName()                
            );           
         }
    }
```

But, how do i get the coupon codes from rule id(i.e passing rule id as the parameter )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this should be work as rule it store in `salesrule_coupon`  table.

you can pass rule_id as parameter and you can get.

```
$oCoupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($ruleId, 'rule_id');
```

hope this will sure help you.